# EF Fluent API - Inheritance mapping Table-Per-Type but one-to-many

Tags: api, frameworks, entity, fluent

I am looking for the EF fluent api mapping syntax of the following scenario.

Suppose I had the following two tables:

Products

- ProductID (e.g. 1, 2, 3)
- ProductName (e.g. Coke, Pepsi, etc.)

StoreSpecificProducts

- StoreSpecificProductID (e.g. 1, 2, 3)
- ProductID (e.g. Pepsi)
- StoreID (e.g. 1)
- ReorderQuantity (e.g. 10)

In the structure above, many stores may have their own version of a product. My class structure recognizes a SiteSpecificProduct as a Product, following the 'is a' rule.

public class StoreSpecificProduct : Product{...}

I can't find any examples that demonstrate a one-to-many inheritance using EF's fluent API and code-first.  I do know that TPT (table-per-type) is close, but all of the examples use a one-to-one example.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**We don't have any one to many inheritance**, I think your question is basically wrong.